# How to do advance filter and sort ( E-commerce ) using Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an E-commerce app using firebase firestore, i am stuck at filtering and and sorting the product on user input. I am able to apply all filter and sort but I want to do the filter on user input and i cannot leave the where clause empty

so i want to generate a fire base query on user input without so if or leave the where clause empty so it doesn't effect the query

how can i generate the query dynamically

````
    .collection('allProducts')
    .where('published', '==', true)
    .where('category', 'array-contains-any', keyword)
    .where('color', '==', colorSelected)
    .orderBy('price')
    .where('price', '>', priceRange[0])
    .where('price', '<', priceRange[1])
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');```
````

Comment: What do you mean through "leave the where clause empty"?

Comment: for example user don't want to filter by color so i will have to leave the colorSelected empty which i cannot do  Or remove the where clause itself.

so i am looking for a way to generate this query dynamically on users selected input

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Firestore queries are immutable. If you try to change the value by calling for example:

```
.where('color', '==', colorSelected)
```

Your query simply becomes a **new** query. To solve this, you have to create a reference to the `allProducts` collection and then add a new filter, according to what the user has selected. This is an example:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const allProductsRef = db.collection("allProducts");
const basicQuery;
if(userHasSelectedColor) {
    basicQuery = allProductsRef.where('color', '==', colorSelected);
} else if (userHasSelectedColorAndCategory) {
    basicQuery = allProductsRef.where('color', '==', colorSelected)
                    .where('category', 'array-contains-any', keyword);
}
```

In this way, you can chain as many function calls as you need.